# value in input text in JSP from result query

Tags: java, jsp

> I have this index.jsp file where all the list of items is displayed and can
>   be updated >by clicking the item name:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <%@ include file="/pages/commons/scripts.jsp"%>
    <title>Pabebe Inventory Store</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:if test="${not empty success}">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Item successfully added.");
            </script>
            <c:remove var="success" scope="request" />
        </c:if>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${not empty user}">
                Hi <c:out value="${user.firstName}" />!<br>
                <a href="LogOut">Logout</a>
                <a href="AddItem">Add new item</a>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                Hello please click <a href="Login">Login</a>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form id="searchItem" method="POST" action="ItemList">
                        <input type="text" id="searchkeyword" name="searchkeyword"
                            value="<c:out value="${searchkeyword}"/>" /><input type="submit"
                            value="Search" />
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form id="resetItem" method="GET" action="ItemList">
                        <input type="submit" value="Reset" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border=1>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Item Description</th>
                    <th>Item Price</th>
                    <th>Item Quantity</th>
                    <c:if test="${not empty user}">
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </c:if>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${items}" var="items">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${not empty user}">
                                    <a href="UpdateItem?id=<c:out value="${items.id}"/>"><c:out
                                            value="${items.itemName}" /></a>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <c:out value="${items.itemName}" />
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${items.itemDescription}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${items.itemPrice}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${items.itemQuantity}" /></td>
                        <c:if test="${not empty user}">
                            <td>
                                <form id="deleteItem<c:out value="${items.id}"/>" method="POST"
                                    action="DeleteItem">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id"
                                        value="<c:out value="${items.id}"/>" /> <input type="submit"
                                        value="Delete"
                                        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?')" />
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </c:if>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and when the item name is clicked, I have another jsp file which is >itemUpdate.jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <%@ include file="/pages/commons/scripts.jsp"%>
    <title>Pabebe Inventory Store</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="UpdateItem" method="POST">
            <table align="center" width="400px">

                <tr>
                    <td>Item name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="itemname" name="itemname"
                        value="<c:out value="${itemname}"/>" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usernameerrmsg}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item description</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="itemdescription"
                        name="itemdescription" value="<c:out value="${itemdescription}"/>" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usernameerrmsg}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item price</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="itemprice" name="itemprice"
                        value="<c:out value="${itemprice}"/>" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usernameerrmsg}" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item quantity</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="itemquantity" name="itemquantity"
                        value="<c:out value="${itemquantity}"/>" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usernameerrmsg}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit"
                        value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
        <a href="ItemList">Go to item list</a>




    </body>
    </html>
```

SO my question is, how do I display the current value of the clicked item in >the input text in itemUpdate.jsp? And when I changed the texts and clicked >submit button, the value in the database will still update. BTW, my update is >working properly. I just wanted to show the current value in the text box when >I'm going to update a specific item.

> [This is what I wanted to happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPtm4.png)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This is my first question and I'm quiet confused how to post correctly. Thanks. :)

Comment: Do you have all these item details in the scope? For me it's like you are passing only the id via url.

Comment: this project has database,java codes, and servlets.

Comment: then i say scope, i'm reffering to the Request scope, the thing you are doint with `${user.firstName}` is retrieving the object from `request` or `session` scope and calling it's `getter` method to retrieve the `firstName` field.